# Question regarding sub-spaces of finitely generated vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $L_1,L_2$ be sub-spaces of finitely generated vector space.
>
> Prove that if $\dim(L_1+L_2)=1+\dim(L_1 \cap L_2)$, then $L_1 \subseteq L_2$ or $L_2 \subseteq L_1$.

Unfortunately, I don't have a clue where to start...

Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know that 
$$\dim(L_1+L_2)=\dim L_1+\dim L_2-\dim(L_1\cap L_2)$$
so with the hypothesis we have
$$\dim L_1+\dim L_2=2\dim(L_1\cap L_2)+1\tag{*}$$
but *by contradiction* if $L_1\not\subset L_2$ and $L_2\not\subset L_1$ then 
$$\dim L_1\ge \dim(L_1\cap L_2)+1$$
and
$$\dim L_2\ge \dim(L_1\cap L_2)+1$$
hence
$$\dim L_1+\dim L_2\ge2\dim(L_1\cap L_2)+2$$
which contradicts $(*)$.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

You know $L_1 ⊂ L_2$ is equivalent to $L_1 ∩ L_2 = L_1$.

So assume $L_1 \not\subset L_2$. Therefore $L_1 ∩ L_2 \subsetneq L_1$. You arrive at:
$$\dim (L_1 ∩ L_2) < \dim L_1 ≤ \dim (L_1 + L_2) = \dim (L_1 ∩ L_2) + 1.$$
Since all dimensions are integers and they already increase once with the “$<$”, you can conclude $\dim L_1 = \dim (L_1 + L_2)$. Else they’d increase twice. Especially, you get $L_1 = L_1 + L_2$, since both spaces have the same dimension and one is included in the other. Now $L_2 ⊂ L_1 + L_2 = L_1$.

All in all: Either $L_1 ⊂ L_2$ or $L_2 ⊂ L_1$.

Comment: Very clear answer, thanks. The conclusion needs to be fixed - $L_1 \subseteq L_2$ or $L_2 \subseteq L_1$